# Showing Interstitial ads every 5 clicks

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, google-mobile-ads

I have an `ElevatedButton` to call family member using `flutter_phone_direct_caller`. I wish to show `interstitial ads` once every 5 clicks user pushes the ElevatedButton. The code below works fine but after 5 clicks, the interstitial ads show up every time.

```
  ElevatedButton(
       onPressed: () {
              admobHelper.createInterad();
              callFamilyMember();
                    setState(() {
                        clickCount=clickCount+1;
                        if(clickCount>5){
                        admobHelper.showInterad();
                    }
                 }
              );
           },
```

Comment: do you ever reset clickCount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with this one. you have to set clickcounts to 0 on show ad.

```dart
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
    admobHelper.createInterad();
    callFamilyMember();
    setState(() {
      clickCount = clickCount + 1;
      if (clickCount > 5) {
        admobHelper.showInterad();
        clickCount = 0;
      }
    });
  }),
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Just out of curiousity.. The interstitial ads show up and proceed to calling and when the call is over, the screen shows the interstitial ads that was shown. Is there a way to show the ads and once user close it, proceed to calling?

Comment: I think there will be a callback where u can showInterad again.